# Thumbnails resized and not cropped in the center

Tags: thumbnails, images, cropping

here's image of some thumbnails in my wordpress homepage: [http://i.imgur.com/x8EmtMO.png](https://i.imgur.com/x8EmtMO.png)

The first one is resized very nicely - I don't know why and how - and the other ones are cropped in the center like it's default in wordpress settings.

So here's my question: how to resize or resize and crop the images to be like the first thumbnail? I came close with the solution using plugin Post Thumbnail Editor, but there were blanks spots above and under the thumbnail which made pretty huge vertical spacing between the posts.

I'd appreciate any answers.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images? Can you paste in the contents of your functions.php file that defines the thumbnail sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Cropping/resizing is also affected by dimensions. If the images have the same  dimensions then the behavior should be exactly the same. From the look of it, it seems that the two images below are bigger than that first image which is why I think they are being cropped in a different way.

I am assuming you have used an add_image_size() for your custom thumbnail size. Now if it is possible to have similar sized artworks before uploading you can probably fix this issue. Sometimes proportions might not be the same since they look like logos. In that case you will have to ensure that the image doesn't take up 100% of it's container.